# Initial variable is not defined in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a `todos` variable declare here:

```
const initialState = {
  todos: []
};

export const todo = (state: RootState = initialState, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case TODO_ADD:
      return {
        todos: [...state.todos, action.payload.todo]
      };
    case TODO_TOGGLE_COMPLETE:
      const todos = [...state.todos];
      todos.forEach((todo: ToDo, index: number) => {
        if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
          todos[index].isComplete = !todos[index].isComplete;
        }
      });
      return {
        todos
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But don't know why it always say not defined

[image]

Comment: *"But don't know why it always say undefined"* It doesn't. It says it's "not defined", which is a different thing. Are you transpiling your code, or running it native in the browser?

Comment: I use TypeScript, not Javascript. I debug on Chrome, and it says like this.

Comment: where is `initialState` defined?

Comment: Can you provide us with a complete example? [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DanielA.White check my update, thanks.

Comment: as a side note, i'd make a separate handler function for each case, I've run into annoying issues with variable scopes in switch statements. So instead of handing the case in the switch, call another function like: `handleTodoToggleComplete(state, action)` or something, and then handle it outside

Comment: @duxfox-- Good suggestion. The OP could even use a dispatch table, e.g. `return (todoHandlers[action.type] || todoHandlers.default)(state, action);`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder interesting, I like that approach

Comment: @MikeTung, sr don't need to provide all code

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this can happen sometimes with compiled/transpiled code (in your case, code compiled by `tsc`). Source maps are good, but they're not perfect.

When you run into this, you may have to fall back to debugging the underlying generated JavaScript rather than using the source maps to make it seem like you're debugging your TypeScript code.